# nodejs runtime stops responding when testing under stress

Tags: mysql, node.js, mocha.js, stress-testing, node-request

I'm basically checking all the routes via request module with mocha.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

I'm doing a stress test, by opening two console windows side by side and running them simultaneously. Most of the time tests are successful, but then an instant comes when the tests fail without timeout error, and from postman I've this specific route that stops responding.

it happens once in around 7 times, and I'm wondering what I could do to figure this out.

**Edit:**
Increased to 4 console windows running tests simultaneously, they ran fine couple of times but then start to timeout.

even no console output on app.get, app.post etc. routes.

Any suggestions?

*Edit*

Caught some request errors based on the suggestion within tests.

```
Uncaught AssertionError: { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' } == null
```

The corresponding code for the above error is

```
request({url: endpoint + "/SignIn?emailAddress=" + emailAddress + "&password=" + password}, function (error, response, body) {

            assert.equal(error, null);
```

**Edit 2**
Dig further deep with console statements and noticed the mysql connection callback was not called. Attaching a screenshot and noticing some connection limit, is it because of this? I'm using connection pools though.

[image]

logs says forcing close of threads.

[image]

**Probable Answer:**

This thread helped with the issue. 
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/405

I set the `waitForConnections: false` and then started to see the error ->

```
[Error: No connections available.]
```

so it seems to me that system was waiting for the connections but test runner didn't wait and ended up with timeout error.

It also seems there's some limit on the maximum number of connections, though I was calling release on connections after each query, not sure how this works on production systems out there? do we have a limit there?

Comment: "even no console output on app.get, app.post etc. routes" Could be that `request` itself isn't able to make it. Have you been handling errors on request?

Comment: How many simultaneous requests of the server are in flight at once?  Some versions of node.js have a fairly low simultaneous sockets limit.

Comment: @laggingreflex good point, I'm going to use `assert.equal(error, null);`, is that okay?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's around 250 I guess, running and testing on my local machine

Comment: I'm also requesting again on results, let's say after signIn route, get the token, make another request, then make a third request etc in a sequence

Comment: Unless you've specifically designed your node.js server to handle that many simultaneous requests, it may not be configured to handle that.  Try backing off your test code to only have X simultaneous requests where you can adjust X starting at 10 and then lowering if you still have a problem or raising if you don't.

Comment: @laggingreflex please check the error of the `request` module

Comment: I went further deep, and noticed that mysql connection pool is not calling back, though I've release statements

Comment: I hope the code will work in production environment, not sure if it's my dev machine mysql that's limited with connections

Comment: turns out that mysql connection pool was not making a callback on pool.getConnection

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of tcp connections. You need to make few changes in system and application level, to make it handle more load.
1. Change your connection setting to keepAlive, wherever possible.
2. On unix, you have ulimit, i.e., the maximum number of file handles that any process can hold at any instant. Remember, in unix every socket is also a file.
3. Manage your time out settings, based on the response time of your database server or another web server.
You'll have to do similar changes at each level of handling request, if you have a multi-tier architecture.